# React-router-dom protected route w/ async

Tags: reactjs, authentication, asynchronous, async-await, react-router-dom

So, I have the following router:

```
 <Router>
   <TopBar />
     <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
     <Route path="/cadastro" exact component={SignUp} />
     <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
     <ProtectedRoute path="/perfil/:profileId" auth={props.auth} exact component={Profile} />
   <Footer />
 </Router>
```

The route `/perfil/:profileId` must be protected for authenticated users only.
My ProtectedRoute component looks like this:

```
function ProtectedRoute({
  component: Component,
  dispatch,
  auth,
  ...rest
}) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isAuthenticated() ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Based on `isAuthenticated()` result, it decides whether user access the page or not. My problem here is that `isAuthenticated()` function makes a request to the server to validate the auth token, so it is asynchronous. I can't just put an async/await inside my isAuthenticated function because this error comes up:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Someone has any ideias on how to solve this? All my authentication logic is on server-side, it makes no sense (to me) to keep only the validation logic on client-side just to solve this problem. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suggest doing is creating a function like this:

```
 const renderContent = () => {
        switch (props.auth) {
            case false:
                return (
                    <Switch>
                         <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                         <Route path="/cadastro" exact component={SignUp} />
                         <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
                         <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />
                    </Switch>
                );
            default:
                return (
                    <Switch>
                       <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                       <Route path="/cadastro" exact component={SignUp} />
                       <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
                       <Route path="/perfil/:profileId" exact component={Profile} />
                       <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/" }} />
                    </Switch>
                );
        }
    };
```

And then in your render method you can do this:

```
 return <div>{renderContent()}</div>;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much.
Just one correction, react-router-dom asks the code to be inside <Router>

Comment: Yes, I know. I usually have my toplevel component inside the App.tsx render <BrowserRouter></BrowserRouter> and then inside that I render a <RouterComponent /> which holds the code from my answer. The code I specified is just for handling routes, but I guess I should have included this in my answer.